# Let $G$ be a graph such that all its vertices have degree 2. Prove that $G$ is a union of pairwise disjoint cycles.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph such that all its vertices have degree 2. Prove that
> $G$ is a union of pairwise disjoint cycles.

This is **Exercise 4.1.4** in the book *Problem-Solving Methods in Combinatorics* by Pablo Soberón.

Since exercises do not have any solutions in the book, I came here to ask for help.

I was thinking of using mathematical induction, since most basic graph properties I saw can be proven using induction. So let's induct on the number of vertices the graph has.

1. Base case: if the graph has one vertex, then the problem is obvious (the graph must be a loop, which is a cycle)
2. Induction step: I don't have any ideas how to do this. I was thinking of considering a subgraph $G'$ that has less than $n$ vertices and also all of its vertices have degree 2.

Please help me! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a vertex $v$.

If it is only connected by a loop with itself, this constitutes a cycle. If we remove $v$ and its loop, we obtain a smaller graph, which by induction hypothesis constsist of disjoint cyces.

If $v$ is connected only to one other vertex $w$ by two edges, then $v,w$ form a cycle. Removing, we obtain a smaller graph, which again consists of disjoint cycles

Finally, if $v$ has two isinct neighbours $u,w$, remove $v$ and edges $vu$, $vw$, and add an edge $uw$. Apply induction hypothesis again and argue that reinserting $v$ between $u$ and $w$ gives you a cycle again.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider a connected component $C$ of $G$. Then the vertices of $C$ have degree $2$. Show that $C$ is a cycle. Note that, more generally, any connected graph with all even degree vertices have an [Eulerian circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Comment: @bof Yes,  this case is simpler, but I think that it is worth pointing out this classic result

Comment: @bof I edited my answer...